# Problem installing VSTO4.0 addin on Outlook 2007

Tags: vsto, installation

I have created an Outlook addin using VS2010 and VSTO 4.0.

On Windows7+Outlook 2010, the installation and and application behaves as expected.

On Vista+Outlook 2007 (fresh installed virtual machine), the installer complains that it does not recognize the .vsto file format.

Has anyone experienced this? When I previously created VSTO3.0 addins and used them on Outlook 2007 I had no problems with installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the VSTO 4.0 runtime (which comes pre-installed with 2010, but not with 2007). You can download it from Microsoft right [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=06C32242-2289-4471-93AA-CE96AA5CBC36&displaylang=en).

If you deploy using ClickOnce this runtime gets added to the prerequisites automatically.

Comment: Thank you. I looked it up and VSTO 4.0 runtime was actually checked to be included (I am using ClickOnce), but for some reason it didn't work. I published again and then I got pass that and on to the next problem which was easier to solve (wrong version of .NET included).